# What is a more specific word for a 'thing'?

Tags: meaning

By thing I mean as in "[how is that still a thing?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8QNDRbjong)" or "people are doing that, is that a thing now?". Things can also happen, as in "[stop trying to make fetch happen.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pubd-spHN-0)"

I suppose things are common behaviours in a group performed and accepted by a substantial number of people. The best specific word I can come up to describe a 'thing' is the term 'phenomenon', but is there something more appropriate?

Comment: **A phenomenon** would seem to fit.

Comment: Good point, I edited my question slightly

Comment: Since it can refer to almost anything - just consider [Last week tonight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8m8cQI4DgM&list=PLgkDZ6LEsTrTXVnCVnkdkA9zydpvxsAqk) :) - a more specific thing might be difficult to find.

Comment: @Helmar Indeed, I actually used that as an example in one of my links!

Comment: @Tom Guess I was kinda blind there, sorry, missed the links

Comment: I don't understand the second sentence of your first paragraph. Can you elaborate or reword?

Comment: Depending on the context, a **trend** or **fad** might work.

Answer (score 2):

'How is that still in vogue ' would do

In vogue refers to the fact that it is still in fashion or the majority take a liking in doing something in a particular vogue.

Example- Traditional dresses like sarees are still -'in vogue'  in india.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, can you try to elaborate on your answer providing links to research which would make people more inclined to up-vote your answer.

Comment: Please read the [tour] and the [how-to-answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) article before answering any more questions.

Comment: @MetaEd Your first outing as a new moderator? Well played!

Comment: This is actually the best answer of those posted.

Comment: Yup!  +1.  Probably the only thing I'd add besides a link, maybe, is I'd put the "in vogue" in quotes or bold it.

Answer (score 2):

According to Thesaurus.com, synonyms of **in-thing** include:

> A go-go, all the rage, chic, chichi*, contemporary, current,
>   customary, dashing, faddy, favored, fly*, genteel, hot*, in style, in
>   vogue, in-thing, last word, latest, latest thing, mod, modern, modish,
>   natty, new, newfangled, now, popular, prevailing, rakish, smart,
>   swank, trendsetting, trendy, up-to-the-minute, upscale, usual,
>   well-liked, with it, á la mode

Take your pick, based on the specific context.

P.S. **In-thing** appears to be equivalent to **thing** in your two examples. You could substitute "an in-thing" in both cases.

Comment: An in-thing is trendy; a thing is just notable for its occurrence.

Comment: @deadrat Just trying to go with the OP's examples, as I understand them. There are certainly other contexts in which one could use *thing*. For example, "Are Dick and Jane still a *thing*?" Still don't understand second sentence of first paragraph.

Comment: Yeah, I don't quite understand the *fetch* reference. Perhaps because it might mean "Stop trying to make *fetch* a thing." And Dick-and-Jane works as a thing, meaning presumably that it still notable in their circle that they're a couple. But that wouldn't make them (or that they're together) an in-thing, would it?

Comment: @deadrat No, it wouldn't. And it wouldn't be an occurrence either, but more of a continuation. An occurrence would be, "And then a *thing* happened. You know, a *thing*. :-)" In the context of the OP's question though, it seems to me that *thing* means *in-thing*.

Comment: I take your point on occurrence. Perhaps *continuing occurrence*? Does it strike you as odd that concrete things are four dimensional, but abstract things (like this thing under discussion) are temporal only? Or is it just me? In any case, I don't think John Oliver's use means in-thing. The example is the *SI* swimsuit issue, which the show treats as embarrassingly out of date.

Comment: @deadrat *Continuing occurrence* could certainly apply in some cases (intermittent events) but wouldn't apply to the Dick-and-Jane ongoing relationship *thing*. It's not obvious that *thing*s are temporal only. For example, "To fix this stupid computer, I need a *thing* (or a *thingamajig* -- defined by M-W as something whose name I have forgotten or do not know)." This whole *thing* thing is multidimensional.

Answer (score 2):

How is that still ***trending***?

I think that would be best especially today as social media has made the whole label of "trending" much a trend itself.

Facebook, Youtube, and Twitter just to name a few!

Answer (score 2):

### The word you are seeking might be "trend".

Or **fad**. (I noticed someone already posted that as a *comment* on the question)
"[H]ow is that still a thing?" becomes "how is that still a **trend**?", and when it comes to stopping "things" from happening, "stop trying to make 'things' happen" becomes "stop trying to make trends happen".

Sometimes, as in the "trying to make happen" sentence above, **meme** is a more appropriate word. (the specific phenomena being railed against is known as "forcing a meme")

If you want to be certain you are referring to a "thing", you can of course as mentioned by other posters use **in-thing**.

Answer (score 1):

How's this still **"an issue"**, **"a mania"** or **"a phenomenon"** may fit.

> - [**"issue"**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/issue) - "something that people are talking about, thinking about, etc."
> - [**"mania"**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mania) -" extreme enthusiasm for something that is usually shared by many people", "an excessively intense enthusiasm, interest, or desire".
> - [**"phenomenon"**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phenomenon) - "something that is very impressive or popular"

A good word or phrase to replace "thing" largely depends on what "thing" you're talking about. When I was a student, my English teacher told us to avoid using "thing" in a composition or essay whenever possible, and try to replace it with a more descriptive word.

> Examples:
>
> - Let me tell you **everything** about... (use **"all the details"**)
> - One **thing** that I won't accept here is vandalism. (use **"behavior"**)
> - Hemingway wrote about many different **things** (use **"subjects"**)
> - Earthquakes and hurricanes are **things**... (use **"natural phenomena"**)
> - This new TV set has some very interesting **things**. (use **"features"**)